# Using Lisp: Write a Common Lisp function named myList which creates the following list and returns it

Tags: list, function, lisp, common-lisp, construction

This was the list given:

```
(4 (7 22) "art" ("math" (8) 99) 100)
```

but I'm still having trouble coming up with the correct code in order to answer this problem

all I have come up with is

```
(defund myList() (4 (7 22) "art" ("math" (8) 99 100) )
```

but obviously that is not correct

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the list so it won't be treated as a function call.

`defund` is a typo for `defun`, and you were missing a close parenthesis.

```
(defun myList()
  '(4 (7 22) "art" ("math" (8) 99 100)))
```

If you need non-constant data, use the `LIST` function to create fresh lists at each level.

```
(defun myList ()
  (list 4 (list 7 22) "art" (list "math" (list 8) 99 100)))
```

Comment: You could argue that this doesn't create a list: `(eq (mylist) (mylist))` will be true.  Whether the original question worried about that I don't know.

Comment: Agreed that a quoted list is both hazardous and unlikely to be a pedagogical goal. I suspect they are looking for precise use of CONS.

Comment: @kennytilton I've added code that creates fresh lists.

Comment: Nice, but usually the instructions for something like this include "...without using LIST". The goal, when this is the case, is to get you deeper into list structure by using CONS. eg, the way to create the list `(42)` using COND is `(CONS 42 nil)`. To create the list `(1 2)` is quite tricky: `(CONS 1 (CONS 2 nil))`. Tbh, LIST is syntactic sugar! And soon enough you will need to see past that sugar when dealing with lists. hth.

Comment: If there are additional restrictions the question needs to say so.